# Stop dynamically created audios

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, html5-audio

I'm playing an audio from a service in Angular but I can't manage to make it stop. Here's my `play()` method:

```
play(item: string): void {
  const audio = new Audio();
  audio.src = item;
  audio.load();
  audio.play();
}
```

Then, in my component I created a `mute()` method where I'd like to stop all audios currently playing:

```
mute(): void {
  const sounds = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
  console.log(sounds);
  for (let i = 0; i < sounds.length; i++) {
    sounds[i].pause();
  }
}
```

However, it doesn't display any sounds in my `console.log` and, therefore, none of them are being paused.

Comment: Not exactly an answer but try using @ViewChildren(). set a common reference #audio on all your audio tags and use @ViewChildren()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementsByTagName('audio')` does not find the audio-tags because they have not been added to the document.

You can add the audio-elements to the document with this line of code at the end of your `play()`-method: `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(audio);`

Alternatively you can keep the audio object in an array and make that array available to your component instead of using `document.getElementsByTagName('audio')`. This approach is considered preferable over direct DOM manipulation in Angular applications.

Answer (score 1):

In your `play` method you created an instance of `Audio` and let it play, but no one other than the browser know about this instance...

Query the DOM will not result in your `Audio` instances...
You MUST hold a list all of the playing audio file/s. and on mute stop them/it.